# Properly mounting a Samba share in Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, server-message-block, share

I am working in a company that uses a Windows AD.

We have a TrueNAS setup with some SMB shares that work well under Windows, but I don't really understand how to properly set them up under Ubuntu.

So I can mount them just fine in Windows and the files are shared using DFS in the AD on all the clients.
This means every client and user is treated individually and when a person creates a file, the owner of the file is the person that created the file.

Now in Ubuntu I am only aware of the possibility to mount a share using fstab and basically using either local TrueNAS or domain credentials to do so. I would like to avoid allowing guest access to those shares for security reasons.

But of course what happens is that all file created, independent of domain user, are always created by the user who created the mount.

So my question is: how do I do this properly under Ubuntu, so every file created shows the proper owner and gets proper permissions.

I am sure there is something out there that I am missing.

Comment: Use NFS instead of SMB.

Comment: The problem is I want to use the existing SMB shares in Linux, not create new ones for Linux. And I read all over the place that sharing the same folder using NFS and SMB brings nothing but trouble. So the goal is to use \\Companyshare\Data\Raw on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `multiuser` mount option. This makes SMB mounts work a bit like NFS mounts, where each user will need to provide their own credentials before being able to access the mounted share.

That is, each user will need to `kinit` for a mount that uses Kerberos (domain accounts), or `cifscreds add` for NTLM (local NAS accounts).

You can have PAM modules do this automatically for each user as they log in; the Linux AD setup procedure might already have done that for you – check `klist` as a user.

(You will still need to specify some credentials for the mount operation itself, but they'll be used only when 'root' is accessing the share, so they can be e.g. the machine account if the Ubuntu systems are domain-joined, or some generic unprivileged account.)

Alternatively: Instead of fstab mounts, have your users access `smb://foo/bar` through the graphical file manager. This is inherently per-user (it uses libsmbclient), and supports Kerberos in the same way.